# invoke cancel on jeditable

Tags: javascript, jquery, jeditable

is there a way to invoke "cancel" on a jeditable area from an external call? (instead of clicking cancel) - basically to close the textarea.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It looks like jeditable exposes a method for "cancel" directly on the DOM element that was used to initialize the editable section.

For example:

```
// A paragraph with jeditable initialized like this:
$('p#editable').editable();

// Could be canceled with:
$('p#editable')[0].reset();
```

Another option would be to trigger the "click" event on the cancel button itself.
In order to do this, we can specify specific html for the cancel button.

```
$('p#editable').editable({
    cancel: '<button class="cancel_button">cancel</button>'
});

// And to cancel:
$('p#editable').find('.cancel_button').click();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also simply do that:

```
('.your_jedit_class').each(function(){
    this.reset()
})
```